# Prevent react native webview from going to youtube website

Tags: javascript, react-native, youtube, react-native-webview

So I'm trying to display a youtube video in my react native app so I started using react native webview. It plays the video just fine, but when you press on the video's title in the webview it goes to youtube.com (screenshots below), which is something I'm trying to prevent.
Thanks in advance!
[screenshot 1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/pcptm.png) [screenshot 2](https://i.stack.imgur.com/OBCWe.png)

Answer (score 0):

Unfortunately there is no very simple solution for this. However React Native's WebView has a prop `originWhitelist` as you can see [here](https://facebook.github.io/react-native/docs/webview#originwhitelist).
You would put your embed URL of the video here (keep in mind it is an array of a single string in this case) and then the relative OS will take care of the handling of the link.

So if you would like to prevent the OS to open an external link in the browser / YouTube app, you would have to implement additional handlers for each OS natively.

Comment: Thank you for your answer! I just ended up using react-native-youtube library instead of webview :)